# Kafka Streams DSL or processor API for DB Changelog Derivation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, debezium

I'm using debezium to capture changes from 4 tables from my bookstore DB, the datamodel is an EAV structure (heavily normalized).

**books:**

[image: database table books]

**book_attributes:**

[image: database table books]

**book_value_int:**

[image: database table books]

**book_value_varchar**
...similar to book_value_int

My goal is to create an output topic that when consumed as a KTable is the equivalent to this:

[image: database table books]

I'm new to Stream Processing, I have made attempts using the KS DSL to join the topics. My efforts so far has been of varying success. Is this the type of operation that is better suited for the processor API?

Comment: "I have made attempts using the KS DSL to join the topics. My efforts so far has been of varying success."  It would help if you shared your code attempts.

Comment: Overall, using the DSL seems to be the right approach. However, as @MichaelG.Noll pointed out, it is hard to help without more details what you tried so far.

Comment: You can use the JDBC Connector to do your joins within MySQL, by the way (like query a database view). No need to read all the topics to streams/tables